# How to setup node.js on a hosting server such as Hostinger, JustHost etc?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, server, port

So I've recently been learning more about Node.js. I've previously done a bit of PHP, but since almost all hosting services provide a preinstalled PHP interpreter I haven't really had any issues there. I've setup Node.js on my own computer but I'm having issues figuring out if it is at all possible to setup Node.js on one of the hosting services I use such as JustHost or Hostinger.

Sorry if I've completely got the wrong end of the stick. This is my first post :)

Comment: this is a host issue, not a coding issue

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have VPS with hostinger and so far I have installed node.js nvm and git. But i need to deploy my application on it from y github repository.

Comment: @codeinprogress Did VPS with Hostinger work? Would you recommend using it?

Comment: @codeinprogress Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw yes just install git on your VPS machine (I had my OS set to Ubuntu) and you can do the normal git clone git pull commands.

Comment: @Larney yes VPS with Hostinger worked but I would not recommend it. A better cheaper option will be AWS EC2. You get billed for the usage instead of a fixed amount monthly

Comment: Alright, I will take note on this. Thank you very much @codeinprogress

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.hostinger.co.uk/knowledge-base/892:

Do you support node.js?
Node.js can only be run on a VPS server.

Comment: I was able to install node using nvm. Look here for more information: https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/#:~:text=Using%20nvm%20(Node.,on%20a%20single%20local%20environment.

Comment: @Fariman Kashani This is a guide to install and run node locally, but the question is specific to hosting.

Comment: ignore the title. It'll work. I used this method to install node on my Hostinger shared hosting account.